# There is not probabilistic measure

Tags: probability

I found some interesting task in book. We have to prove that there is not probabilistic measure $P$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $P(A_k)=\frac{1}{k}$ for any $k\geq 1$, where $A_k:=\{nk:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: what book is the question from?

Comment: This is from the polish book "Introduction to the theory of probability" written by Jakubowski and Sztencel.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_{1},...,p_{n}$ be diferent prime numbers. It's easy to see that the set of events $Ap_{1},...,Ap_{n}$ is independent.
By hypothesis, $Pr(Ap_{i}) = 1/p$, so the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Pr(Ap_{n})$ diverges. Now, by using Borel-Canteli's theorem, you get a contradiction, because there is no number divisible by an infinite number of primes! So there's no probabilistic measure.

Comment: Could you write me where is the contradiction? I can use Borel=Cantelli but I cannot see contradiction.

Comment: In this case, Borel-Canteli states that $Pr(lim sup Ap_{n}) = 1$. Remember: lim sup $Ap_{n}$ is the set of natural numbers that belong to an infinite number of $Ap_{n}$. That is, there's a natural number n that is divisible by an infinite number of primes! Here is the contradiction.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much for answer :)